# Data Migration breaking in production when using bulk_update

Tags: python, django, digital-ocean, django-migrations

My application is deployed on Digital Ocean's App Platform for Django. The database is PostgreSQL.

The following data migration has run correctly in my local environment. In production it starts but never ends running, so the deploy is automatically cancelled.

This data migration affects more or less 40.000 lines in the database.

```
from django.db import migrations

def link_answers_to_default_segment(apps, schema_editor):
    """Create a default segment for each company"""
    Company = apps.get_model('brand_score', 'Company')
    Segment = apps.get_model('brand_score', 'Segment')
    Answer = apps.get_model('brand_score', 'Answer')

    for company in Company.objects.all():
        default_segment = Segment.objects.create(company=company, name='default')

        answers = Answer.objects.filter(participant__company=company)
        for answer in answers:
            answer.segment = default_segment
        
        Answer.objects.bulk_update(answers, ['segment'])

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('brand_score', '0025_auto_20211209_1412'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(link_answers_to_default_segment, reverse_code=migrations.RunPython.noop),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the code to save in each iteration, thus removing the bulk_update. Then it's worked!

```
for company in Company.objects.all():
        default_segment = Segment.objects.create(company=company, name='default')

        answers = Answer.objects.filter(participant__company=company)
        for answer in answers:
            answer.segment = default_segment
            answer.save()
```

I still don't know why it works now but not before. And if it's a Django or Digital Ocean issue.

If somebody knows why does it behaves like this, would be nice.